# The number of the system of distinct representatives (SDR)

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> Given a set family $\mathscr{A}=(A_1,A_2,\cdots,A_n)$. An ordered sequence $(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$ is called an *SDR* if
>
> - $a_i \in A_i$ for $i=1,\cdots,n$;
> - $a_i \ne a_j$ for any $i \ne j$.

Given two set families $\mathscr{A}=(A_1,A_2,\cdots,A_n)$ and $\mathscr{B}=(B_1,B_2,\cdots,B_n)$. If for any $1 \le k \le n$ and $1 \le i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_k \le n$, we have
$$\left|\bigcup_{j=1}^k A_{i_j} \right| \ge \left|\bigcup_{j=1}^k B_{i_j} \right|.$$

> Can we prove that the number of SDR of $\mathscr A$ is not less than the number of SDR of $\mathscr B$?

I think it is true, but I don’t know how to prove it.

Comment: I have checked that it's true for $n=1,2,3$.

Comment: This is a question related to Hall's theorem in graph theory. I don't know whether it is related to group theory.

Comment: If you strengthen the hypothesis to $$\left|\bigcup_{j=1}^k A_{i_j} \right| = \left|\bigcup_{j=1}^k B_{i_j} \right|$$ then I guess you can prove that the number of SDR of $\mathscr A$ is equal to the number of SDR of $\mathscr B$, is that right?

Comment: Yes, I think it is right. Assume that it has been proved and then, how to prove the problem introduced by me?